# Adding an Excel Worksheet to a WPF Window

Tags: wpf, excel

I have a requirement where i need to add an excel worksheet to a WPF application, here the Excel worksheet should be fully functional (with the ribbon and Etc;) and it has to appear side by side with the existing controls (Inside a ViewBox maybe)

thanks in advance!

Comment: rather than bring excel into a wpf app, why not create an addin for excel directly?

Comment: @user.... Have you thought your way through the security issues that need to be resolved before that can happen?